# Making it possible to do a Fourier transform on it: $\frac{1}{(k+w)^2(a^2 +w^2)}$

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, spectral-theory, partial-fractions

Sorry for all the edits, I'm very stressed and not so used to Latex.
Full question: consider a filter with impulse response

$$h(t)=e^{-bt} u(t)$$

where $u$ is the unit step function.
The input signal is a wss with spectral density

$$S_{xx}(t)= \frac{a}{w^2 +1}$$

Find:
A) the spectral density of the output
B) the autocorrelation of the output
C) the power of the output

My original question:
How to break these up so it's possible to do a Fourier transform on it:

$$\frac{a}{(k+w)^2(1 +w^2)} -> \frac{a}{k^2 +1}(\frac{1}{w^2 +k^2}-\frac{1}{w^2 +1})$$

I don't know how to perform the partial fraction of a equation like this and it have taken me a long time to find anything..

My attempt at a similar question but with the nominator 1 instead of a
[image: My attempt at a similar question but with the nominator 1:]

My exam on stochastic processes is tomorrow and this knowledge is needed for at least one question per exam if not more.

Comment: Depending on what $k, w$ and $a$ are, you could use partial fractions no?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do but I just get a bunch of terms = 0 so I'm not doing it correctly. k and a are variables, w is the frequency.

Comment: Why don't you provide us with the entire question so we can help you properly.

Comment: @Mattos I added the original question and will try to provide you with my result with all the terms of 0

Comment: Can you check my edit to your post to make sure my edit is what you were asking (Note, you'll need to learn to use latex for your math text. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

Comment: @Mattos Thanks a bunch, I will make sure to learn it for my questions in the future.
It looks correct, I was having some internet connection problems but it seems to be working fine now after rebooting my computer. I will try to upload my embarrassing attempt now.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{a}{(k+w)^2(w^2+a^2)} = \dfrac{A}{k+w} + \dfrac{B}{(k+w)^2} + \dfrac{Cw+D}{w^2+a^2} \implies$$

$$\dfrac{a}{(k+w)^2(w^2+a^2)} = \dfrac{A(k+w)(w^2+a^2)+B(w^2+a^2)+Cw(k+w)^2+D(k+w)^2}{(k+w)^2(w^2+a^2)}$$

$$\implies a = Aw^3+Awa^2+Akw^2+Aka^2+Bw^2+Ba^2+Cw^3+2Ckw^2+Cwk^2+Dk^2+Dw^2+2Dkw$$

$$\implies 0w^3+0w^2+0w+a = w^3(A+C)+w^2(Ak+B+2Ck+D)+w(Aa^2+Ck^2+2Dk)+(Aka^2+Ba^2+Dk^2)$$

The system is

$$
\begin{align*} 
A+C = 0\\
Ak+B+2Ck+D = 0\\
Aa^2+Ck^2+2Dk=0\\
Aka^2+Ba^2+Dk^2 =a
\end{align*}$$

From this you can solve the values and remeber, $a$ and $k$ are constanst

Comment: Since they are constants I still have to keep them and adapt them all the way right?

Comment: Yes, that's the main idea. Now, if you have the values of $a$ and $k$, try to plug them and solve the system.

Comment: I don't have them, that's the part I don't really know what to do with. From that I'm supposed to take the fourier transform and keep the constants as constants

Comment: Also, check this  [link](http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/equations/solve/advanced.jsp#c=solve_advancedsolveequations&v1=A%2BC%3D0%0AAk%2BB%2B2kC%2BD%3D0%0AAa%5E2%2BCk%5E2%2B2Dk%3D0%0AAka%5E2%2BBa%5E2%2BDk%5E2%3Da&v2=A%0AB%0AC%0AD)

Comment: Remember that the fourier transform and its inverse are linear, so $F[\frac{A}{(k+\omega)} + \frac{B}{(k+\omega)^2}+\frac{C\omega}{\omega^2+a^2}+\frac{D}{\omega^2+a^2}] = AF[\frac{1}{k+\omega}]+BF[\frac{1}{(k+\omega)^2}]+CF[\frac{\omega}{\omega^2 +a^2}]+DF[\frac{1}{w^2+a^2}]$

Comment: Can't really tell what you wrote there, and I'm bad with latex so I can't fix it. But I got the solution and attached a picture

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a Brazilian friend, thanks so much for all the help. 
I feel a bit silly now but without asking I wouldn't have found it out. 
[image: solution]

Comment: Nice you got the Answer! But the Initial equation differs from the one you showed to us

Comment: Yes I'm so sorry about that, apparently I had a big misunderstanding when I wrote the parenthesis.